# How do have both count and percent on barcharts in ggplot2? R

Tags: r, ggplot2

this is my data

```
data <- data.frame("Name" = c("Mark", "Jenny", "Linn"),
                   "Freq" = c("5","7", "3"),
                   "Percent" = c("33%", "47%", "20%"))
```

This is my plot

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Name, y=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black", fill="dodgerblue1")+
  geom_text(label=data$Freq, vjust=-1)
```

How can I have both my percent label next to my freq label preferably in parenthesis or separated by a comma?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Compose the text label with `paste/paste0`.

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Name, y = as.numeric(Freq))) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "dodgerblue1")+
  geom_text(label = with(data, paste(Freq, paste0('(', Percent, ')'))), vjust=-1) +
  ylim(0, 8)
```

[image]

Comment: @FruityPebblePug Rui's labels are very nice here, but the proportions are wrong in your bar chart because of the way your data is formatted. 7 is not 3 times larger than 3, nor 1.5 times as large as 5. You will be misleading whoever your audience is if you don't convert the factors to numbers first.

Comment: @AllanCameron I appreciate the concern, I just quickly came up with this dataframe and didn't realize it was not formatted correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is important that if you want to plot numeric variables you make sure they are numbers, rather than factors as in your example, otherwise the proportions will be wrong:

```
data$Freq <- as.numeric(as.character(data$Freq))
labs <- paste0(format(100 * data$Freq/sum(data$Freq), digits = 4), "%")

ggplot(data, aes(x=Name, y=Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black", fill="dodgerblue1")+
  geom_text(label = labs, vjust=-1) + coord_cartesian(ylim = c(0, 8))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The first excellent answer uses a simple general strategy for labeling each bar, but did not work in my hands because as.numeric(Freq) returns c(2,3,1), not the expected c(5,7,3) (as a result, I could not reproduce the chart shown).  The third answer fixes the factor problem, but does not label the bars as asked in the question.  The simple solution would be to have the Freq numbers be numbers, then the first answer works:

```
data <- data.frame("Name" = c("Mark", "Jenny", "Linn"),
                   "Freq" = c(5,7,3),
                   "Percent" = c("33%", "47%", "20%"))
```

And, once we have numbers, we can have 'R' calculate percentages:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = Name, y = Freq)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "black", fill = "dodgerblue1") +
  geom_text(label = with(data, sprintf("%d (%.0f%%)",Freq, 100*Freq/sum(Freq))), vjust=-1)+
  ylim(0,8)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=Name, y=Percent)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color = "black", fill="dodgerblue1")+
  geom_text(label=paste0("N = ",data$Freq), vjust=-1) +
  ylab("")
```

[image]

Comment: This is good to have! but the other response was what I needed