# Adding the text of count and percentage by the group in a bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, group-by, bar-chart

I have a data frame which is coded below

```
    Variable=c("ABC","ABC","MNO","MNO","XYZ","XYZ")
Flag=c("Y","N","Y","N","Y","N")
Count=c(1234,9876,6789,3210,5500,7890)
df<-cbind(Variable,Flag,Count)
df<-as.data.frame(df)
```

I want to plot a bar graph that will show basically the count and the percentage of Y and N for each group.I have done this until now

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Variable,fill=Flag))+ geom_bar(position = "dodge")+
  stat_count(aes(label=paste0(sprintf("%1.1f", ..count../sum(..count..)*100),
                              "%n", ..count..), y=1*..count..), 
             geom="text", colour="white", size=4, position=position_dodge(width=1))
```

This shows the count
For percentage I have tried this

```
temp <- df %>% group_by( Variable, Flag) %>% 
  group_by(Variable) %>% mutate(percentage = 100*(Count/sum(Count)))

ggplot(temp, aes(x = Variable, fill = factor(Flag),y=percentage)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_text(aes(label = percent(percentage)), vjust = 0.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = percent)
```

I don't now how to bring them together in one plot in R.

I want something as same as  this to be produced
[image: Bar-chart that is needed]

Comment: Hi. This is one of the most commonly asked questions in this tag. see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29869862/how-to-add-percentage-or-count-labels-above-percentage-bar-plot, or google your exact question and this is giving at least 20 results - please elaborate why those don't help you

Comment: No, I have tried these and failed to add both at the same time.

Comment: Bro, I have tried many things and could not get the answer. That's why I used this platform. I need to add both at the same time where I am finding it difficult.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158913/how-do-have-both-count-and-percent-on-barcharts-in-ggplot2-r

Answer (score 3):

```r
df <- mtcars

library(tidyverse)
fg <- df %>%
  count(cyl) %>%
  mutate(
    perc = round(proportions(n) * 100, 1),
    res = str_c(n, "(", perc, ")%"),
    cyl = as.factor(cyl)
    )

ggplot(fg, aes(cyl, n, fill = cyl)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = res), vjust = -0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Can you do this for my dataframe?

Comment: @Prabhu You can just replace it and extend it to your data frame!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is by first creating a 'percent' variable, then plot wit `geom_col` and `geom_text`. We can `paste0` "Count" and "percent" to have the desired labels.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot)

df_for_plot<-df %>% group_by(Variable)%>%
    mutate(proportions = scales::percent(Count/sum(Count), 0.01))

df_for_plot %>% ggplot(aes(x = Variable, y = Count, fill = Flag)) +
    geom_col(position = 'dodge') +
    geom_text(aes(label=paste0(Count, '(', proportions, ')'))
```

[image]

Comment: But, this only gives the percentage. I want to add count too

Comment: For that see the updated answer

Comment: Or see the duplicate pointed out by @tjebo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158913/how-do-have-both-count-and-percent-on-barcharts-in-ggplot2-r